# Can "As [adjective] as [noun] is" in the beginning of the sentence mean "Although/despite [noun] is [adjective]"?

Tags: meaning

In a blog post about web development, I found an interesting phrase:

> As awesome as CSS counters are, don’t forget about our old friends `ol` and `li`.

From the context, it seems to mean "Although/despite [one Web technology feature] is awesome, don't forget about [other Web technology feature]". But I have never seen "as ... as" in this meaning. What is the correct meaning of this phrase and what kind of "as ... as" usage is this?

Comment: "*As silent as a cat*" is attributing the quality of silence to the high degree which cats enjoy is; "*As silent as a cat **is**, ...*" with the copula and comma, is about to introduce a big old **but**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction is recent, and is a modification of the more traditional construction

> Awesome as CSS counters are, ...

which is a somewhat literary form meaning

> However awesome CSS counters are, ...

I believe (but I have not researched the matter) that the construction arose by confusion with the different construction

> (Something is) as awesome as CSS counters.

Answer (score 1):

Think of 'He is as rich as a king', 'The water is as deep as an ocean' etc.

Now, it is not a big step to 'As rich as this man is, he has an unhappy life', 'As deep as the water is, I can still see the bottom'.

And another step gets you to 'As awesome as CSS counters are, don't forget...'.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit the second step? What is the rule of this kind of "as ... as" usage, and where can I read more about this?

Comment: @Ilya Streltsyn I suppose there are words which are elided '(Although I am) as tall as I am, I cannot reach the top shelf'. Alas, I cannot advise on rules etc, because I am a native speaker and just know it instinctively.